# error in Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have following Linq:

```
var ownerRegistryId = 731752693037116688;
var excludeTypes = new[]
{
    "CA00", "CA01", "CA03", "CA04", "CA02",
    "PA00", "PA01", "PA02", "PA03", "PA04"
};

var maxStateChangeMonth = 4;
var excludeStatusId = 999;
var includeMortgage = new[] { "CL10", "CL11", "PL10", "PL11" };

 var sum = (
    from account in context.Accounts
    from owner in account.AccountOwners
    where owner.AccountOwnerRegistryId == ownerRegistryId
    where !excludeTypes.Contains(account.AccountType)
    where account.StateChangeDate == null ||
        (account.StateChangeDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month)
            <= maxStateChangeMonth
    where includeMortgage.Contains(account.AccountType) ||
            account.AccountType.Contains("Mortgage")
    where account.AccountStatusId != excludeStatusId
    select account.MinimumInstallment)
    .Sum(minimumInstallment => Math.Abs(minimumInstallment));
```

but I get the error:

> The cast to value type 'Decimal'
>   failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's
>   generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type.

this error comes as soon as I add this:

```
where (includeMortgage.Contains(account.AccountType) ||
    account.AccountType.Contains("Mortgage"))
```

If I remove this from above query, it works.

The query is translation of following SQL:

```
    SELECT Sum(ABS([Minimum Installment])) AS SumOfMonthlyPayments FROM tblAccount 
    INNER JOIN tblAccountOwner ON tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID] = tblAccountOwner.
    [Creditor Registry ID] AND tblAccount.[Account No] = tblAccountOwner.[Account No] 
    WHERE (tblAccountOwner.[Account Owner Registry ID] = 731752693037116688)
     AND (tblAccount.[Account Type] NOT IN 
    ('CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04'))
    AND (DATEDIFF(mm, tblAccount.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 
   4 OR tblAccount.[State Change Date] IS NULL AND ((tblAccount.[Account Type] IN ('CL10','CL11','PL10','PL11')) OR
    tblAccount.[Account Type] LIKE 'Mortgage')) AND (tblAccount.[Account Status ID] <> 999)
```

Comment: @Guffa: error is: The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: Is this a compile error or a runtime error.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: I cleaned up your LINQ statement. Changed a bunch of `&&` operators to `where` operators. Much more readable now.

Comment: What type is `account.MinimumInstallment` exactly?

Comment: @Steven: It is decimal. If I change it to decimal? I get error in math.abs which doesnt take decimal?

Comment: Have you tried changing to `decimal?` and using  `Math.Abs(minimumInstallment.HasValue ? minimumInstallment : 0)`?

Comment: @Yakimych: I get : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Abs(sbyte)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Yakimych: Please edit the question so that it contains the code that you are actually using. There is little point in looking for an error in code that you are not even using.

Comment: Math.Abs(minimumInstallment.HasValue ? minimumInstallment.Value : 0)

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Not sure that's the error I expected to see, but try `Math.Abs(minimumInstallment.HasValue ? minimumInstallment.Value : (decimal)0)` instead. Pretty sure the cast to decimal is redundant, but you can try both ways just in case.

Comment: @Yakimych  same error with this even :(

Comment: Please can you retest your original assertion that this does not occur if you remove the clause `where (includeMortgage.Contains(account.AccountType) || account.AccountType.Contains("Mortgage"))` - this doesn't sound to me like this should introduce the error your are describing.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: There is little point in making any suggestions on some other code than the one that you are actually using.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Did you solve this issue? "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Abs(sbyte)' has some invalid arguments" sounds like you are returning a Nullable<T> somehow and Intellisense + compiler gets upset. How about `Math.Abs(minimumInstallment ?? 0m);`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to rewrite the last two lines of your query like so:

```
var sum = (
...
select account)
.Sum(a => Math.Abs(a.MinimumInstallment));
```

That's how I interprete this part of the exception `"...or the query must use a nullable type"`. By using the projection `select account.MinimumInstallment` you have a non-nullable type, namely `decimal` which is the type of `account.MinimumInstallment`.

Not sure though, just a guess.

**Edit**

The problem might actually be the final assignment `var sum = ...`. Since you don't specify the result type explicitely the compiler will here infer the type to `decimal` because `MinimumInstallment` is decimal. The query can actually return `null` when the selected recordset was empty so the cast to decimal is impossible.

So, let's help the compiler to infer the result type of the query to `decimal?`:

```
var sum = (decimal?)(from ... ) ?? 0;
```

(Replace `from ...` by your original query or maybe by my modified version above.)

**Edit 2**

OK, the first Edit didn't work (according to comment in another question). Indeed I could reproduce the issue in a similar example. But the following worked in my example:

```
var sum = (
    ...
    select account)
    .Sum(a => (decimal?)Math.Abs(a.MinimumInstallment))
    .GetDefaultOrValue();
```

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: I have a new "Edit 2". I could reproduce the problem in a simpler example. The Edit 2 worked for me, just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try using:

    Math.Abs((decimal)(minimumInstallment.HasValue ? minimumInstallment : 0));</del>

How about:

```
 Math.Abs((decimal)(minimumInstallment!= null ? minimumInstallment : 0));
```

Comment: I tried it and get : The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: How about this? `Math.Abs((decimal)(minimumInstallment != null ? minimumInstallment : 0));`

Comment: Same thing, but I'd probably use null coalescing instead of the ternary if. `Math.Abs((decimal)(minimumInstallment ?? 0));`.  Also if you do use the ternary, always use .HasValue not !=null